# Sumifs in excel 3 criteria in columns

Tags: excel-2010

I am working on a Sumifs that has 2 different criteria in Col B and the 3rd criteria in Col F.
If all 3 criteria are met then I am going to sum the values in Col Q.

I have this so far and it returns a 0. I tried to tweak it every way I am aware of and still no luck.

```
=SUMIFS($Q$4:$Q$2700, $B$4:$B$2700, "=AUS", $B$4:$B$2700, "=VCO", $F$4:$F$2700, "=TRB")
```

Comment: The value in column `B` cannot be both `AUS` AND `VCO`. It has to be one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you provided returns 0 every time because the value in `B` cannot be both `AUS` AND `VCO`, it's one or the other.

As far as I know (someone correct me if I'm wrong), there's currently no way to have a conditional statement in a single criteria range (e.g. `"=AUS" OR "=VCO"`). A workaround could be the following:

> =SUM(SUMIFS(Q4:Q8,B4:B8,{"AUS","VCO"},F4:F8,"=TRB"))

[image]

This sums the values in `Q` if `B` equals either `AUS` OR `VCO` **AND** `F` equals `TRB`

Comment: Thank you to all. You are very clairvoyant. I did not have the either request between AUS or VCO combined with TRB. Sorry I will slow down next time I type my question. This 2nd answer Sum(Sumifs work perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear it was able to solve your problem. Please remember ot mark the question as solved by marking the correct response as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you reference $B$4:$B$2700 twice. Because this column can not possibly be both AUS and VCO Column Q will never be summed.

To make this work, add a new column next to column B. Make the value of cell C4 equal to the value of B4 (=B4) and drag this formula to cell B2700 (you can also just double click on the bottom right corner of the cell to make it auto-fill to B2700). You can then use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS($Q$4:$Q$2700, $C$4:$C$2700, "=AUS", $B$4:$B$2700, "=VCO", $F$4:$F$2700, "=TRB")
```

Remember to indicate if this answer worked!

Comment: What if he already has 2700 rows in column B that already contain either VCO or AUS? Moving them to column C is not as trivial a task as you make it seem.

Comment: Was just wondering the same. Currently testing a solution for this case using  "=OR(B4='AUS',B4='VCO')" but Excel does not seem to like the single quotes. I will update my answer to indicate how to duplicate the data in column C

Comment: Thank you to all. You are very clairvoyant. I did not have the either request between AUS or VCO combined with TRB. Sorry I will slow down next time I type my question. The 2nd answer Sum(Sumifs work perfect.